# how to conditionally subscribe to another observable on success of first observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I m tring to use concatmap and complete the observables sequentially when queryParams has id it should only call getbearer tokens or else it should navigate to error with securekey but in reality its going to error page with bearer-token

```
const result = this.activatedRoute.queryParams.pipe(
        concatMap((params) => {
          if (params.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
            sessionStorage.setItem('secureKey', params.id);
            return this.httpServiceService.getBearerTokens();
          } else {
            this.router.navigate(['error'], {
              queryParams: { 'error-key': 'secure-key' },
            });
          }
        })
      );
      result.subscribe(
        (response: any) => {
          if (response.access_token) {
            sessionStorage.setItem('bearerToken', response.access_token);
            this.router.navigate(['summary']);
          } else {
            this.router.navigate(['error'], {
              queryParams: { 'error-key': 'bearer-token' },
            });
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          this.router.navigate(['error'], {
            queryParams: { 'error-key': 'bearer-token' },
          });
        }
      );
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I think `concatMap` is just asking for a race condition (I don't know how often and how easy the query parameters change, though). I would use `switchMap` instead, because I imagine that the moment we navigate from `"?id=alice"` to `"?id=bob"`, the matter of Alice's token becomes immaterial.
2. Generally, conditionally subscribing to another stream should work just fine with `switchMap` and `filter`:

```
firstStream$.pipe(
    filter(result => someCondition(result)),
    switchMap(result => getAnotherStream(result))
).subscribe(//...
```

Oh, and by the way, your `concatMap` returns a stream only `if (params.hasOwnProperty('id'))`. Does that even compile? Return an observable in the `else` branch as well, it could even be `EMPTY`, but probably should be `throwError`.